# MVC, CSS, and 302 authentication Hell

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, authentication, model-view-controller, http-status-code-302

Like most people with the same question, everything under my "Content" folder is currently being redirected to my login page (until I've been authorized).  According to Dev HTTP Client, this is what I get when I try navigating directly to one of the style sheets under Content.

[image]

I've tried the following:

1. **Allowing anonymous users to access a bunch of different folder via the web.config**:

   [image]
2. **I've tried changing permissions on IIS.**  The folder of the website has full permissions, and too all of it's subfolders.  I've even added **Network Service** user and **DefaultAppPool** user, and given them full permissions, also.
3. **I've changed the Anonymous Authentication for the site to be Application Pool Identity**

What am I missing?

Comment: I forget...with the authorization stuff, does `*` include `?`?  I thought i remembered having to specify them both for some reason...

Comment: Interesting idea, but doesn't work.  I just added both and didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're setting Anonymous authentication to the ApplicationPool Identity you need to give the ApplicationPool Identity permission to that folder. To do this follow the next steps:

- Go to the properties of your content directory
- Select the "Security" tab
- Click the "Edit" and then "Add" button
- Click the "Locations" button and make sure you select your machine. (Not the Windows domain if the server belongs to one.)
- Enter "IIS AppPool\nameofyourapppool"
- Click the "Check Names" button and click "OK".

Comment: Hi Kenneth. I appreciate the response, but I already did that (#2 above).  Didn't help.

Comment: What user is your application running under? ApplicationPoolIdentity, System or something else?

Comment: ApplicationPoolIdentity

Comment: What type of authentication are you using? Windows or forms? Since it's a 302 and not a 401 I actually think the file permissions are OK...

Comment: I'm using forms authentication.  I've wired up the membershipprovider to do this for me.

Comment: Then your IIS and folder security are probably set up just fine. Could you show me how you configured the anonymous user access in your web.config?

Comment: I'm trying, but for some reason it doesn't appear when I post it in the question here.  I'll take a screen shot and post now.
... done.  See above.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize to everybody, but it would seem the answer was obvious (and my fault).  In all the changes I made, I guess I had accidentally disabled the anonymous authentication on my Content folder.

So stupid...